# 'The System.Workflow.* types are deprecated. Instead, please use the new types from System.Activites.*'

Tags: migration, workflow-foundation, .net-4.5, rule-engine, type-providers

We are currently upgrading our solution from .net 3.5 to .net 4.5. During which we are facing the below error

> 'System.Workflow.ComponentModel.Compiler.TypeProvider' is obsolete:
>   'The System.Workflow.* types are deprecated. Instead, please use the
>   new types from System.Activites.*'

The below code creates a TypeProvider to allow additional types be available inside  WF Rules Engine which we have. This is used in the RulesValidaton constructor as the below code shows

```
TypeProvider typeProvider = new TypeProvider(null);
typeProvider.AddAssemblyReference(typeof(T).Assembly.Location);
typeProvider.AddAssemblyReference(typeof(ValidationClass<T>).Assembly.Location);

RuleValidation ruleValidation = new RuleValidation(typeof(ValidationClass<T>), typeProvider);
```

I googled for how the same can be achieved using the System.Activities.* namespace but wasn't able to find any. Please do direct me to an appropriate replacement for the TypeProvider class in .net 4.5.

Answer (score 2):

This functionality has been completely redone in .NET 4.5. Now you are able to run multiple instances, and Micorosft has done a great job (believe it or not) in their .NET 4.5 Examples to show how this can be done.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj205427.aspx

Here is some of the key code, and obviously would be different for the different types of workflows, to do something to a particular "instance" of the workflow.

ActivityBuilder wf = StartUpdate("StateMachineNumberGuessWorkflow.xaml");

StateMachine sm = wf.Implementation as StateMachine;

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Will look into the example.

Comment: I actually have JUST completed a working example so let me know if you run into issues, I can provide you with some code

Comment: Sure Jeff. Will let you know.